# True in Goal State Coq

Tags: coq, proof-assistant

While attempting to prove `All` in [Software Foundations Volume 1, Logic.v,](https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/lf-current/index.html) I came across a proof state of simply `True`. I.e. my proof state looks like:

```
T : Type 
P : T -> Prop
H : forall x : T, False -> P 
==================================
(1/1)
True
```

I understand that simply using `reflexivity` should get my to my goal. But, I don't understand why, or what it means for the proof state to simply be `True`. What does this mean? And why does reflexivity work here?

Comment: Maybe you should rephrase the title: you want to know why `reflexivity` works, not how to solve the goal.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Coq to print the definition of any term: `Print True.`

The response is:

```
Inductive True : Prop :=  I : True.
```

From this response, we see that `True` is a proposition, and that `I` is (by fiat) a proof of `True`.

When you have something like `H : forall x : T, False -> P` in your context above, it means `H` is a proof of `forall x : T, False -> P`, so that if your goal were to be `forall x : T, False -> P` then you could prove this goal using the command `exact H.`

In general, whenever you have `H : P` where `P` is a proposition, then `H` is a proof of `P`.

Accordingly, in this case, you have `I : True`, and your goal is `True`, so you can prove this goal using the command `exact I.`

Answer (score 0):

Looks to be an undocumented but harmless behaviour of `reflexivity`
(see [the doc](https://coq.inria.fr/doc/V8.18.0/refman/proofs/writing-proofs/equality.html#coq:tacn.reflexivity)).
For such a goal, I usually call `easy` (`constructor` or `split` work too).